# Android 4.2 Device Orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I have a problem on android 4.2. I'm trying to figure out, if the screen is in landscape or portrait orientation. I am aware of the following ways of doing this:

1. This works perfectly except it that this is depreciated after API level 8

   ```
   Display display = ((WindowManager) 
                 getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
   int orientation = display.getOrientation();
   ```
2. This is the preferred method for figuring out orientation on android 4.2. However this method only returns rotational degree, and incorrect for figuring out current device configuration (landscape or orientation)

   ```
   WindowManager wManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
   int rotation = wManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
   ```

I need to know what the current rotation is (landscape or portrait) regardless of the default orientation of the device. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose I could override the onWindowFocusChanged method and figure out the width and height of the screen and if the width is greater then the height the screen is in landscape, otherwise portrait. Let me know what you guys think of that if its an efficient way to recognize orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
   Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

It will tell you whether its Landscape or Portrait, but won't differentiate for Reverse (i.e. Reverse Landscape).

You can also override the onConfigurationChanged method

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration _newConfig)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
// code
} else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
// code
}
```